# Prove that if $\dim(U+W)=1+\dim(U∩W)$, then $U⊆W$ or $W⊆U$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> $U,W$ are subspaces of $V$. Prove that if $$\dim(U+W)=1+\dim(U∩W)<\infty,$$ then $U⊆W$ or $W⊆U$.

I'm really struggling here.

Comment: If you [edit] the question to show us some of your struggle we may be able to help.

Comment: Start with some simple cases like $\mathbb{R}^3$ then see if you can generalize.

Comment: The truth is that I don't even know how to approach this question. I've tried using the dim(U+W)=dim(U)+dim(W)−dim(U∩W) theorem to get to a simpler expression that will only be true if U is a subset of W or vice versa, but haven't really gotten that far.

Comment: Using the dimension formula it follows $2dim(U+W)-1=dim(U)+dim(W)\leq2\text{max}\{dim(U),dim(W)\}$. Hence $dim(U+W)\leq\text{max}\{dim(U),dim(W)\}+\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I got to that exact inequality, I didn't know how to continue from there

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): edit your post to include your attempts, even if they failed.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your equation rewrites $$(\dim U-\dim(U\cap W))+(\dim W-\dim(U\cap W))=1$$ hence one of these two summands is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1 + \dim(U \cap W) = \dim(U+W) \geq \dim(U) \geq \dim(U \cap W)$, and we see that at least one of these inequalities must be an equality. So, either $\dim(U + W) = \dim(U)$, or $\dim(U) = \dim(U \cap W)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: if dim(U+W)=dim(U)
 then, W⊆U
and if dim(U) = dim(U∩W) 
then U⊆W?

Also, I don't quite understand why at least one of these inequalities must be an equality.

Comment: If both inequalities are strict then the chain increases the dimension of the intersection by at least $2$.

Comment: Oh that's super useful and helpful, thank you both!

Comment: You're welcome. You should upvote the answer as well as accept it.

Comment: I've accepted the answer, Unfortunately I cannot upvote because I just created this account and I haven't hit the 15 reputation requirement for upvoting.